# Condition inside string is not working - angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I want to show a different icon depending on the if my value is true or false

```
<span><i class="fas fa-caret-"+({{ extendedOptionsContainer ? "down" : "up" }})+"></i></span>
```

So if extendedOptionsContainer  is true, icon will be down, and if its not it will be up, but this wont work because inside this string and "", any help?

Comment: Using `ngClass` with whole class name looks more elegant to me: `<i class="fas" [ngClass]="extendedOptionsContainer ? 'fa-caret-down' : 'fa-caret-up'"></i>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <span><i [ngClass]="'fas fa-caret-' + (extendedOptionsContainer ? 'down' : 'up')"></i></span>
```